# Can't send email in production

Tags: python, django, deployment, smtp, celery

I am developing online shop and everything worked fine on local machine.Client add item to cart, enter his credentials click 'Make Order' and than order confirmation should be sent to his email. And it was working fine, even with redis + celery, but since when I've deployed project to server (linode.com), order confirmation doesn't work. Worker took tasks but never execute this. I thought it was due to celery, and I've made decision to make sending email without task manager and queue. But it didn't help.

I use UFW firewall in the server:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW       96.126.119.66             
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I get error like this:

> [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Hope you will help me to understand the issue

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://bauerdress.ru/orders/create/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
 'cart.apps.CartConfig',
 'orders.apps.OrdersConfig',
 'wishlist.apps.WishlistConfig',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'crispy_forms',
 'information.apps.InformationConfig',
 'promotion.apps.PromotionConfig',
 'django_filters',
 'email_sub.apps.EmailSubConfig',
 'django_simple_coupons',
 'ckeditor',
 'flower',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kirill/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/kirill/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/kirill/bauer_dress/orders/views.py", line 46, in order_create
    order_created(order.id)
  File "/home/kirill/bauer_dress/orders/tasks.py", line 22, in order_created
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject, None, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [order.email, settings.MAIL], html_message=html)
  File "/home/kirill/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/home/kirill/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/kirill/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/kirill/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 62, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 308, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)

Exception Type: TimeoutError at /orders/create/
Exception Value: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from cart.cart import Cart
from .models import OrderItem, Order
from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from shop.models import Product
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django_simple_coupons.forms import CouponApplyForm
import weasyprint
from django.template import loader
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from email_sub.models import Subscription
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from .tasks import order_created




 def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    coupon_apply_form = CouponApplyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            if cart.coupon:
                order.coupon = cart.coupon
                order.discount = cart.coupon.discount.value
            order.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=order,
                    product=item['product'],
                    product_set=item['product_set'],
                    price=item['product_set'].price,
                    quantity=item['quantity'],
                    size = item['product_set'].size_set,
                    color = item['color']
                )
            try:
                Subscription.objects.get(email=order.email)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                Subscription.objects.create(name=order.first_name, surname=order.last_name, email=order.email)
            
            order_created(order.id) # <--- order confirmation email 
            cart.clear()
            if cart.coupon:
                cart.clear_coupon()
            return render(request, 'orders/order/created.html', {'order': order})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'orders/order/create_v2.html', {
        'cart': cart,
        'form': form,
        'coupon_apply_form': coupon_apply_form})
```

tasks.py

```
def order_created(order_id):
    """
    Task for sending mail if order created
    """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Заказ #{}'.format(order.id)
    html = loader.render_to_string('orders/order/mail2.html', context={'order': order})
    send_mail = send_mail(subject, None, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [order.email, settings.MAIL], html_message=html)
    return send_mail
```

settings.py (part of smtp settings)

```
#smtp
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myuser@gmail.com' #real data used in production
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '1234'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Comment: Gmail is not suitable for use as a production mail server. Just enter "smtp.gmail.com" into the search bar and find more than 10k question of people having problems with it.

Comment: ok, thank you a lot, what then should I use? Services like SendGrid?

Comment: We do not give recommendations for external services on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I use **Linode** and linode blocks ports, found out it accidentally
As I've read GoDaddy does the same thing

> Need to send mail from your Linode? New Linode accounts have ports 25,
> 465, and 587 blocked by default. To have these restrictions removed,
> please review this guide, then open a Support Ticket after creating
> your Linode.
>
> In an effort to fight spam, Linode restricts outbound connections on
> ports 25, 465, and 587 on all Linodes for new accounts created after
> November 5th, 2019.